# Visual Studio 10 doesn't open my c# file anymore?

Tags: c#

I did some c# exercise at school but now these exercise gives me so many errors and warnings, it seems they are all corrupeted or something maybe when I deleted duplicated files with ccleaner I ***ed all up. Now I must recovery those c# exercise!! When I debug vs10 tell me if I "would like to continue and run the last successful build". If I hit yes it runs the exercise It was, so where vs10 took the exercise that worked? Can I get it from this? I must recovery those c# exericse please help me ! If I just copy the code it's a way to handle this but I need the graphic form with all of it's component in their position, does exist a way to copy the graphic form? (sorry my english) I'll posts all the errors it gives to me, but if I can resolve it with just by copy and paste it's ok. Plese help, Thank You!

[VS10 output when I debug c# exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hcm0.png)

[Errors and warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gjev.png)

Comment: Here is one of mine exercise 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjkzkvji1957s1e/gioco%20del%2015.zip?dl=0

Comment: Make backups, or better yet use a revisioning system like github so you can roll back when stuff is messed up.

Comment: @AngeloMartino you are going to have to improve the English of this question. Are you opening GiocoDel15.sln in Visual Studio? If so that is good. Next clean and rebuild.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm opening the .sln , clean succeeded but rebuild failed.

Comment: @AngeloMartino but why did the build fail? You do not actually need that much English in your question, you need to show screenshots of the build error messages

Comment: Thank you so much ! I appreciate everyone for their patience and I'm so sorry about the post not so well made. Thank you all.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new on this site, next time I'll be more accurate making better post so it can be useful to others, but I doubt someone would encounter this kind of problem I had, sorry I just realized it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `System.Windows` reference.

1. Right click your project in vstudio
2. Click Add Reference
3. Go to the **.NET** tab (this is where all the .NET assemblies can be found)
4. Search for `System.Windows`
5. Check it & then click OK.

Comment: Sorry I'm doing something wrong? https://gyazo.com/0546f42d0d9ee662fece3a8182ebc9fd

Comment: @AngeloMartino updated my answer, I musn't have been specific enough.

Comment: Wow it really worked !!!! I clicked on System.Windows.Forms then on OK and it magically works !

Comment: @AngeloMartino No magic to it. It just looks like you may have accidentally removed the reference.